# How can I send signals from C to QML?

Tags: c++, signals, qml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ SIGNAL to QML SLOT in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834147/c-signal-to-qml-slot-in-qt)

How can I send signals from `C++` to QML?
I have no problems using Connect() to connect signals from QML to a `SignalHandler` in `C++`.
But is there any way to do it the other way around? I have been trying to get that to work but
QML says **Unknown Signal** when creating a signal handler in QML.

So I would like to in C++ emit a signal:

```
emit mySignal();
```

In QML receive the signal:

```
onMySignal:
{

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can have the answer here
[a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834147/c-signal-to-qml-slot-in-qt)

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: First of all you need to create your own custom classe in qt.