# How to call a QML function from c++ in BB10

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

How to call a QML function from c++ code in BB10.?

My QML function-

```
function loadingData(data) {
    evaluateJavaScript("createChart('" + data + "')")
}
```

Now how can I call this "loadingData" function from c++.

Please help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ SIGNAL to QML SLOT in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834147/c-signal-to-qml-slot-in-qt)

Answer (score 2):

> First, not clear on BB10, what i know is on desktop, but the method maybe no difference;
>
> two way:
>
> 1) signal and slot; refer to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html#receiving-signals
>
> 2) metaObject
>
> example(qt 4.8):
>
> you would need an ID in your QML element, so that we can get the object in C++:

```
QDeclarativeView* mpView = //get view from whatever function  
QObject *rootObject = mpView->rootObject(); //this is the rootObject of QML view  
QObject *obj = rootObject->findChild<QObject *>(/*your element ID*/);  
if (obj != NULL)   
{  
    QVariant data = // what you need put in;  
    bool ret = QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "loadingData",  
        Q_ARG(QVariant, data));  
    if (!ret) QDebug<<"invoke failure.";  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access property of QML element from C++ easily, but calling function is going to be difficult.

But instead you can emit a signal from c++ and connect a function in qml to signal and execute required code there.

Expose C++ object to QML

```
qmlDocument->setContextProperty("_someClass", someClass);
```

which has signal defined say `someSignal()`

When ever you need to call QML function , `emit someSignal()`

```
emit someSignal()
```

In QML connect function to C++ signal

```
someClass.someSignal.connect(qmlFunction);

function qmlFunction() {
    ...
}
```

You can find details information [here](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/dev/integrating_cpp_qml/).