# Sending a signal to a QML item from C++ (Qt5)

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a QML file containing this:

```
Text {
    id: testData
    onTaskClicked:{
        testData.text = task.name
    }
}
```

The catch is this taskClicked signal. It is emitted by another widget (C++) and needs to be relayed to QML.

This is similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834147/c-signal-to-qml-slot-in-qt), except that the solution posted there doesn't work (why is written below).

The C++ code:

```
ctxt->setContextProperty(QLatin1Literal("holiday"), m_model);
ctxt->setContextProperty(QLatin1Literal("bgcolor"), color);

view->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

auto mainPath = QStandardPaths::locate(QStandardPaths::DataLocation,
                                           QLatin1Literal("taskview.qml"));

view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(mainPath));

ctxt->setContextProperty(QLatin1Literal("viewer"), m_view);
```

`m_view` is a `QListView` subclass that emits the `taskClicked(HolidayTask* task)` signal (from the .h file):

```
Q_SIGNALS:
    void taskClicked(HolidayTask* task);
```

`color` and `m_model` are registered in QML and are used elsewhere. The object from the signal is already registered in QML. `view` is my `QQuickView`.

First I tried the solution presented in the question above:

```
auto root = view->rootObject();
auto myElement = root->findChild<QObject*>(QLatin1Literal("testData");

connect(m_view, SIGNAL(taskClicked(HolidayTask* task), myElement,
        SLOT(taskClicked(HolidayTask* task);
```

However, `myElement` is always null (and I get a runtime warning about a non existent slot).

If I try to set the view (the QListView) pointer as a context property of the QML view, it still doesn't work.

In all cases, I get also:

```
QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onTaskClicked"
```

What could I possibly be doing wrong here?

EDIT to clarify some details: `HolidayTask` is a custom QObject subclass, and the signal `taskClicked` is defined in C++ (in a `QListView` subclass)

EDIT2: We're getting close, but no cigar:

```
auto root = quickView->rootObject();
auto myElement = root->findChild<QObject*>(QLatin1Literal("testData"));

connect(m_view, SIGNAL(taskClicked(HolidayTask*)),
        myElement, SIGNAL(taskClicked(HolidayTask* task)));
```

and

```
Text {
    id: testData
    objectName: "testData"
    signal taskClicked(HolidayTask task)
    onTaskClicked: {
        testData.text = task.name
        console.log("CLICk!")
    }
}
```

yields

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QQuickText_QML_0::taskClicked(HolidayTask* task) in /home/lb/Coding/cpp/holiday-planner/src/mainwindow.cpp:178
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'testData')
```

More details: HolidayTask, my custom QObject subclass, is registered in the code as

```
qmlRegisterType<HolidayTask>("HolidayPlanner", 1, 0, "HolidayTask");
```

Minimal QML with the data:

```
 import QtQuick 2.0
 import QtQml 2.2

import HolidayPlanner 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: container
    objectName: "container"
    color: bgcolor


   Text {
        id: testData
        objectName: "testData"
        signal taskClicked(HolidayTask task)
        onTaskClicked: {
            testData.text = task.name
            console.log("CLICK")
        }
   }

}
```

EDIT3: The final, working code is (see answers on why)

```
 connect(m_view, SIGNAL(taskClicked(HolidayPlanner::HolidayTask*)),
        myElement, SIGNAL(taskClicked(HolidayPlanner::HolidayTask*)));
```

This worked **only** through the use of objects with full namespaces. Otherwise the signature will not match in QML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, `myElement` is always null (and I get a runtime warning about
>   a non existent slot).

You are trying to find the child based on id, whereas it is based on the objectName property. You would need to set the objectName property to the desired to actually find it.

Also, you do not seem to declare the signal in your QML Text item. I am not sure if it is a custom C++ item or a built-in one. You have not shared enough code unfortunately to understand that bit. Either way, declare your signal [as per documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#signal-attributes).

Therefore, try this code out:

```
Text {
    id: testData
    objectName: "testData"
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    signal taskClicked (HolidayTask task)
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    onTaskClicked:{
        testData.text = task.name
    }
}
```

Once that is done, you are almost ready. You need to have your HolidayTask registered to QML for sure, and you also need to change the connect syntax in your main.cpp as follows:

```
connect(m_view, SIGNAL(taskClicked(HolidayTask* task), myElement, SIGNAL(taskClicked(HolidayTask* task)));
```

In short, you need to trigger your QML signal handler this way, and not via `SLOT`.

Also, note that your connect syntax is broken as it is missing the closing brackets at the end. That needs to be fixed.

I would even consider removing the pointer assignment and use value or reference based passing for this.

Comment: The signal is from C++, and the item is custom. I'll update the post.

Comment: @Einar: OK, but then I would suggest not to call it `Text` as there is such a default qml element. I would suggest to call it something more specific for your purpose. In that case, you can declare the signal in C++, too, but IMHO, the qml signal declaration is still much simpler. :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I was mistaken - by "item" I meant `HolidayTask`. `Text` is built-in. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Einar: ah, ok, that simplifies things. I think declaring the signal in QML is the simplest in here, IMHO.

Comment: Added more code: we're getting ahead, but there are still small issues.

Comment: @Einar: I think it is because the qml signal is declared without pointer. Try to get rid of the pointer in your C++ code to match the value semantics until it works. You can fine-tune it later. Let me know if that works, then.

Comment: I figured it out! The signature needs to have the complete namespace (everythign is under a namespace). I was doing "HolidayTask" without the attached namespace, and apparently this doesn't bode well with QML. I'll post the revised code in the question to keep track for others.

Answer (score 4):

You can connect a signal from C++ to QML by:

```
 view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("testData",this);
 QObject::connect(this,SIGNAL(taskClicked(HolidayTask* task)),(QObject *)view->rootObject(),SLOT(onTaskClicked(HolidayTask* task)));
```

When your signal is named `taskClicked`, The slot in QML should be `onTaskClicked`.

Also in QML you should name the object `testData` by:

```
objectName: "testData"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onTaskClicked"
```

The error tells you that your `Text` item do not have signal `taskClicked` or property `onTaskClicked`!
You need to declare a slot inside your text item. To do that, you simply declare a function:

```
Text {
   id: testData
   objectName: "testData" // as Laszlo said

   function onTaskClicked( task ) {
       testData.text = task.name;
   }
}
```

But that also won't work because you create a `SLOT( onTaskClicked(QVariant) )`  instead of  `SLOT(taskClicked(HolidayTask*))`. In order to exchange data with QML you need to change your signal to `SIGNAL(taskClicked(QVariant))`:

```
Q_SIGNALS:
    void taskClicked(QVariant task);
```

And emit it with:

```
emit taskClicked( QVariant::fromValue( task ) );
```

Remember that in order to be able to use `HolidayTask` it must be a `QObject` that is  registered with `qmlRegisterType`.

You can also [simply call that qml function](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#invoking-qml-methods).

If you are not able to use QVariant you can declare a signal inside you Text object:

```
Text {
   id: testData
   objectName: "testData" // as Laszlo said

   signal taskClicked ( HolidayTask task )

   onTaskClicked: {
       testData.text = task.name;
   }
}
```

And then connect from a C++ SIGNAL to qml SIGNAL:

```
auto root = view->rootObject(); 
auto myElement = root->findChild<QObject*>(QLatin1Literal("testData");
connect(m_view, SIGNAL(taskClicked(HolidayTask*), myElement,
    SIGNAL(taskClicked(HolidayTask*));
```

Comment: As I wrote above, this trigger a non-existant signal runtime error.

Comment: @Einar It should be exaclty `SIGNAL(taskClicked(HolidayTask*))` without the "task" parameter name.