# How to do QObject::connect to QJSValue?

Tags: qt, qml

If Qml can do

```
MyComponent.connect(someJsFunction);
```

how can I do this on c++ ???
I need connect JSValue if it isCallable without workarounds. I want to know how it makes qml engine...

```
QObject::connect(QObject, signal, QJSValue, evaluateFunctionSlot);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As result the best workaround:

**qml**

```
function connect(name, fn){
    myObject[name].connect(fn[name]);
}
```

**c++**

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(MyObject, "connect", Q_ARG(QVariant, "anySlotName"), Q_ARG(QVariant, QVariant::fromValue(data)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. I got the solution from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71060709/525038). That said, I don't know if it aligns with the Qt way of doing it. Their [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#invoking-qml-methods) of invoking a QML method uses [QMetaObject::invokeMethod()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod).

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QQuickView>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void cppSignal(const QString &msg);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view(QUrl(u"qrc:/75069400/main.qml"_qs));
    view.show();

    QObject *item = view.rootObject();
    MyClass myClass;
    QObject::connect(&myClass, SIGNAL(cppSignal(QString)),
                     item, SLOT(callFromCpp(QString)));

    emit myClass.cppSignal("this is a test");

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick

Rectangle {
    width: 320
    height: 240

    function callFromCpp(value : string) {
        console.log("QML" , value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply, but it is not QJSValue. I need connect QObject signal to QJSValue slot as like as QJSValue.call(). I know how to do an workaround but it's not interesting.