# Couldn't catch signal from C++ in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

I'm trying to transfer some `QString` from `c++` to `QML`. Here are the steps I've done so far.

1. Created a class inherited from `QObject` and defined `signal` in it.

```
class exampleClass: public QObject {

Q_OBJECT

signals:
void mySignal (QString myStr);

}
```

2. Somewhere in the class implementation, I `emit` the `signal` i.e.

```
void exampleClass::exampleFtn( . . . ){
.
.
qDebug("Before transmitting Signal");        // This gets triggered
emit mySignal ("Hello from CPP");

}
```

3. In my `main.cpp`, I've initialized the class and expose it to `QML` i.e.

```
int main(...) {

.
.
exampleClass *exampleObj= new exampleClass(&app);
Engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("exampleObj",  exampleObj);
}
```

4. And finally, in `QML` i have connected the `signal` i.e.

```
Window {

.
.
Connections {
        target: exampleObj
        function mySignal(myStr) {
            console.log("signal from C++ recieved !")    // Doesn't get triggered
            console.log(myStr)                           //  Doesn't get triggered
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The signal on the QML side would be `onMySignal`. Where do you call `exampleClass::exampleFtn`? Are you sure you*re calling it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66617238/525038

Comment: function onMySignal(..) worked. One has to capitalize the first alphabet, I get it now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for connecting to a signal named `foo` in `Connections` is `function onFoo() { ... }`.
In your case it would then be :

```
Connections {
    target: exampleObj
    function onMySignal(myStr : string) { // the type annotation doesn't hurt
        console.log("signal from C++ received !")
        console.log(myStr)
    }
}
```